# Hyperlink to local file

Tags: pdftex, hyperlink

I am trying to include a clickable hyperlink in my document. I am able to do it with websites, but I struggle to find a solution for clickable hyperlinks to include other documents on my computer.

I have tried the following, but when I try to click on the link nothing happens:

> \href{run://This PC/Documents/Lectures/Lecture 1.pdf}{Lecture 1}

I have included these libraries:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

Comment: As always you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example. I don't think you should expect PDF viewers to gennerally support some `run` protocol as that might be a big security issue

Comment: If the current PDF and `Lecture_1.pdf` (I would never use spaces in filenames as they often need to be escaped) is in the same folder, then `\href{Lecture_1.pdf}{Lecture 1}` should work (depending on PDF viewer, works in my Evince). Also note that this is computer independent, `This PC/Documents/Lectures/Lecture 1.pdf` is not.

Comment: Thank you very much - that worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally links like `\href{run://...}{..}` might not be supported for security reasons.

On the other hand of PDF file `A.pdf` is in the same folder as the file you are working on then

```
\href{A.pdf}{Some text}
```

usually works. And have the added bonus that it also works if the folder is moved to a different computer.